# How to connect to VM with NAT via SSH protocol? (Qemu/KVM)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, kvm, nat

I need your advice.

Brief to my question:

I got two Linux/Ubuntu 18.04 Lts. machines.
First one is the host(SSHD) and has a VM machine installed on it(virtual machine's ethernet is configured as NAT: Qemu/KVM - virtualization).
Simple SSH connection between host and VM on it in NAT regime works perfectly:
ssh user@ip.address > pass

First machine is connected to router via LAN and second machine is a ssh-client connected to a router via Wifi.

machine1(host machine, LAN) > Router < (wifi) machine2(SSH Client)

Is there any solution to access VM(on host machine) with machine that is connected to wifi network only? I'm pretty new with Unix/Linux, so I would really appreciate your support with this case.

ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.122.x  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255

P.S. I would prefer not to switch NAT to bridge regime. If you need more data, I will gladly provide you with some more details.

Comment: You need to configure **port forwarding** on machine1, e.g. port 2222 forwarded to port 22 on the VM guest. There should be various ways to implement it, including adding a netfilter rule with the `iptables` command. Since this is a common requirement, you will find plenty of tutorials on the internet. **Alternatively**, it might also be possible to create a route to the VM's address on machine2, with machine1 as router.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh to the physical host from your client, and to the VM from the physical host, then simply....

```
ssh -J physuser@phys.example.com vmuser@vm.example.com
```

(alternatively create a ssh_config for vm.example.com with the ProxyJump set to phys.example.com)

Answer (score -1):

If you have KVM Manager (GUI), you can follow this guide with no issues. The process is the same: [VMware Workstation port-forwading](https://superuser.com/questions/1595477/how-to-ssh-into-linux-host-in-vmware-workstation-15/1595900#1595900)